# How to Insert element tag in specific location without closing tag in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, hubspot

Anyone has an idea how to insert HTML tag in specific location eg. I want to insert  tag in the upper part of the body and the closing tag is at the footer. I want to insert these codes using jquery how's that possible

```
<HTML>
     <body>
          <main>

               <div id="hs_cos_wrapper_widget_1606595393534"></div>
               <div id="#hs_cos_wrapper_widget_1606763490257"></div>
           </main>
      </body>
</html>
```

Here is my current code, as you can see there are two div Ids for the insertion before and after

```
 <script>
      $( "<main>" ).insertBefore( "#hs_cos_wrapper_widget_1606595393534" );
      $( "</main>" ).insertAfter( "#hs_cos_wrapper_widget_1606763490257" );
  </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot insert opening and closing tags in separate operations. You can only create whole elements.

That being said, jQuery has a method to do what you require; [`wrapAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/wrapall):

```js
$('#hs_cos_wrapper_widget_1606595393534, #hs_cos_wrapper_widget_1606763490257').wrapAll('<main />');
```

```css
main {
  border: 1px solid #C00;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hs_cos_wrapper_widget_1606595393534">Foo</div>
<div id="hs_cos_wrapper_widget_1606763490257">Bar</div>
```

Comment: Thank you This is what I need